# Migrate data from a link table into target table

Tags: mysql, data-structures, migration

I have two tables. One (let's call it `a`) is currently a link table with data in like this

```
| c_id  | t_id  |
|-------|-------|
|   1   |   8   |
|   1   |   9   |
|   2   |   8   |
|   3   |   8   |
|   4   |   9   |
```

and another (`t`) with data like this

```
|  id   | code  | value |
|-------|-------|-------|
|   1   |  AB   |  0.9  |
|   2   |  BC   |  0    |
|   3   |  IM   |  0    |
|   4   |  MC   |  0    |
|   5   |  VI   |  0    |
|   6   |  BC   |  0.9  |
|   7   |  MC   |  2.5  |
|   8   |  VI   |  2.5  |
|   9   |  BC   |  2.5  |
```

`t_id` in table `a` is a foreign key mapping onto `id` in table `t`, which is an auto incremented ID.

Due to functionality changes, I now want the data from `a` to replicate the linked row in `t` and add the required `c_id` (and then table `a` to be dropped) so you get something like this;

```
|  id   | c_id  | code  | value |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
...
|  25   |   1   |  VI   |  2.5  |
|  26   |   2   |  VI   |  2.5  |
|  27   |   3   |  VI   |  2.5  |
|  28   |   1   |  BC   |  2.5  |
|  29   |   4   |  BC   |  2.5  |
```

which will enable me to change the `value` column per `c_id`, rather than globally. The new rows can safely be added to the end of the table - or perhaps it would be better to have a new table with this information in.

Is there a query that can do this? I hope I don't have to do it by hand!

Comment: Trigger might help you...

Comment: @SMA I've been looking down the barrel all afternoon, so you might be right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, since you mentioned modifying tables, this is a one-time procedure.

You won't be able to add the rows to the end of either of the existing tables, since you have different column requirements. You'll have to either make a new table or modify the existing one. I chose the former, and then you can populate it using `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE new_t (id SERIAL, c_id INT, code VARCHAR(2), value FLOAT);

INSERT INTO new_t (c_id, code, value)
    SELECT a.c_id, t.code, t.value FROM a INNER JOIN t ON (t.id = a.t_id);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6765/2